# Hilbert Spaces and Projections

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $\{Y_{t}: t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is a stationary zero mean time series. Consider the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ generated by the random variables $\{Y_t: t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with inner product $$ \langle X, Y \rangle = E(XY)$$ and norm $$||X||^2 = E|X|^2$$

Consider the subspace $\mathcal{M}$ generated by the random variables $\{Y_u: u \leq t \}$. Why are future values found by projecting onto the subspace $\mathcal{M}$? For example, why is $Y_{t+1}$ found by $\mathcal{P}_{\mathcal{M}}Y_{t+1}$?

Comment: What are the properties satisfies by a time series?